# what is the difference between stackpane and root in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I was practicing for javafx for doing pie chart. Following are the codes for developing pie chart. If i do with the `Group` and with the `StackPane`,I find no difference in the output.I have commented the Group part.Just wandering the difference between the two.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class ChartApp1 extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
PieChart pieChart = new PieChart();
//Group p=new Group();

pieChart.setData(getChartData());
primaryStage.setTitle("PieChart");
StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(pieChart);
//p.getChildren().add(pieChart);
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 250));
primaryStage.show();
}
private ObservableList<PieChart.Data> getChartData() {
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> answer = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
answer.addAll(new PieChart.Data("java", 17.56),
new PieChart.Data("C", 17.06),
new PieChart.Data("C++", 8.25),
new PieChart.Data("C#", 8.20),
new PieChart.Data("ObjectiveC", 6.8),
new PieChart.Data("PHP", 6.0),
new PieChart.Data("(Visual)Basic", 4.76),
new PieChart.Data("Other", 31.37));
return answer;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html),

> **StackPane** lays out its children in a back-to-front stack. The z-order of the children is defined by the order of the children list
>   with the 0th child being the bottom and last child on top. If a border
>   and/or padding have been set, the children will be layed out within
>   those insets.
>
> The stackpane will attempt to **resize** each child to fill its
>   content area. If the child could not be sized to fill the stackpane
>   (either because it was not resizable or its max size prevented it)
>   then it will be **aligned** within the area using the alignment
>   property, which defaults to Pos.CENTER

While the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) for the `Group` class states that

> A **Group** node contains an **ObservableList** of children that are
>   **rendered** in order whenever this node is **rendered**. A Group will take on the collective bounds of its children and is not directly
>   **resizable**.
>
> Any transform, effect, or state applied to a Group will be applied to
>   all children of that group. Such transforms and effects will NOT be
>   included in this Group's layout bounds, however if transforms and
>   effects are set directly on children of this Group, those will be
>   included in this Group's layout bounds.
>
> By default, a Group will "auto-size" its managed resizable children to
>   their preferred sizes during the layout pass to ensure that Regions
>   and Controls are sized properly as their state changes. If an
>   application needs to disable this auto-sizing behavior, then it should
>   set autoSizeChildren to false and understand that if the preferred
>   size of the children change, they will not automatically resize.

Answer (score 2):

`StackPane` is a container object; it is used to lay out nodes in a specific manner (back-to-front, according to z-order). Functionally, `StackPane` is a layout manager. The term root or *root node* refers to the top-most node in the scene graph of a JavaFX application. The root node is passed to the constructor of the `Scene`; it is the only node that does not have a parent. `Group` is a container too. It is not a layout manager; it places its children in absolute coordinates. `StackPane` and `Group` can be root nodes.

You would see a difference between `Group` and `StackPane` if you wanted to place your chart at a specific location in the application's client area. Placing a chart at x=10 and y=10 would work with `Group` but would not work with `StackPane`.